# Question regarding Logic sign circle +

Tags: logic, notation

I am doing a multiple choice test, and they say that

$(p\oplus q)\land q$ is logically equivalent with $\neg (p \land q)$

I am confused about this, because normally I can verify with a truth trable, But I do not understand $\oplus$ could someone explain this for me?

Comment: It means exclusive or, so the statement $p \bigoplus q$ is true only when p or q is true, but not both. Also, pretty sure the statement $(p \bigoplus q) \land q$ is not equivalent to $\neg (p \land q)$ so you might want to double check if you copied it correctly.

Comment: $(p\oplus q)~\land~q\equiv (\neg p\land q)$, with the negation inside the bracketting.